# TarantoolConnection16 is not thread-safe

Tags: java, tarantool

Using one TarantoolConnection16 instance concurrently causes "bronken pipe" exceptions. [A trivial connection pool](https://gist.github.com/bashnesnos/18b0423f9eb29159698c) fixes the problem.

Have I missed a proper thread-safe connection class or misused the one from example somehow? The things I've made not like in the example from the library's [readme](https://github.com/tarantool/tarantool-java) is that I've reused a connection and schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TarantoolConnection16 has state and can't be thread safe. You should use any open source connection pool. Try Apache Commons Pool for example.

Comment: But is TarantoolConnection16 JDBC-compliant to use it with an JDBC connection pool?

Comment: Sorry, I mixed up Apache DBCP with [Apache Commons Pool](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/)

Comment: That's cool, but a DB driver is not really useful without a pool. It would be hard to maintain and add additional implementaion complexity. Are there any plans to add a default pool implementaion?

Comment: Yep, I'll present high performance thread safe async driver in next release.